# Making prototype function in JavaScript on attaching to string should modify and print it Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to make a function alpha such that if I do:

```
"hello".alpha(5)
```

then it should output hello string 5 times in a row.

I know how to make such a function, but don't know how to use prototype so that it would work if I attach that in a manner shown above. Can someone help out?

**My Function:**

```js
str1 = "hello";
function alpha(num, str) {
  var temp = "";
    for (i=0; i<num;i++){
      temp+=" " + str;
    }
  return temp;
}
console.log(alpha(10, str1));
```

Comment: `String.prototype.alpha = ...`?

Comment: The `prototype` property offers very powerful ways of extending functionality to a built-in object type. Just make sure it will not interfere with code you might be using from external libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
String.prototype.alpha = function(num) {
  var temp = "";
    for (var i = 0;i < num;i++){
      temp += " " + this.valueOf();
    }
  return temp;
}
console.log("Hello".alpha(10));
```

Comment: Be careful when using variables in a function. Always make sure to declare them with `let` or `var`. Your variable ( in this case `i`) might otherwise interfere with outside code.

Comment: @cars10m well i just copy pasted his code, i'm usually carefull about this. thanks for pointing this out, i edited the post

Answer (score 0):

I played around a bit further and found this alternative form:

```js
String.prototype.alpha=
 function(num,sep){return Array(num).fill(this).join(sep||" ");}
   
console.log("hello".alpha(3));
console.log("hi".alpha(5,','));
```